# Чи ставиться крапка після грн?

Tags: пунктуація

Скорочене слово **грн** з **гривня** підкреслює як помилку. У правописі не трапляється жодне з цих скорочень.

Логіка підказує: крапка після скорочення ставиться тільки в тому разі, якщо воно створене через усічення кінця основи слова, на кшталт: *ст. (століття), р. (рік)* тощо. Якщо ж кінцева літера скорочення відповідає кінцевій літері основи нескороченого слова — крапка не потрібна. У такому разі йдеться про стягнення. Отож *млн (мільйон), млрд (мільярд), грн* *(гривня* — **я** тут закінчення*)* — крапок не потрібно.

Як все-таки правильно?

Answer (score 5):

**Коротко:** **грн** без крапки.

Існують також инші варіянти:

- **грв.**
- **₴**

---

Наведу за вас чинного — 2015 року — правопису:

[§ 40. Графічні скорочення](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil1.htm#par40)

> Від абревіатур слід відрізняти умовні графічні скорочення, які вимовляються повністю й скорочуються лише на письмі. Графічні скорочення (крім стандартних скорочених значень метричних мір: *м — метр, мм — міліметр, см — сантиметр*) пишуться з крапками на місці скорочення, при цьому зберігається написання великих та малих літер і дефісів, як і в повних назвах: *півн.-сх.* (північно-східний), *півд.-зах.* (південно-західний), *Півн. крим. канал* (Північнокримський канал).
>
> […]
>
> Слова не скорочуються на голосну, якщо вона не початкова в слові, і на **ь**. Наприклад, слово селянський може бути скорочене: *сел.*, *селян.*, *селянськ*. При збігу двох однакових приголосних скорочення треба робити після першого приголосного: *стін. календар, ден. норма*. При збігу двох (і більше) різних приголосних скорочення можна робити як після першого, так і після останнього приголосного, залежно від структури слова: *власноруч.* або *власноручн. (власноручний)*, але тільки: *власт. (властивий)*.

Дійсно, нічого не каже про скорочення через останьої букви.

[Словник скорочень](http://abbrs.info/?text=%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8F) вказує на:

- напис **грн** без крапки;
- існування **грв.** — за правописом;

---

Згадаємо, що за норми також відповідають [державні стандарти України](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%96_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D0%B8), а з [переліку](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%94%D0%A1%D0%A2%D0%A3) можна побачити який саме стандарт:

[ДСТУ 3582-97 Інформація та документація. Скорочення слів в українській мові у бібліографічному описі. Загальні вимоги та правила](http://library.nlu.edu.ua/POLN_TEXT/Zurnal/NO_BOOK/GOST/DSTU%203582_97.htm)

> **3 ВИЗНАЧЕННЯ**
>
> **Стягування** — скорочування слова вибірковим пропусканням приголосних та голосних літер.
>
> **Відсікання** — скорочування слова відкиданням двох або більше літер в кінці слова.
>
> **4.2** Під час скорочень слів застосовують відсікання, стягування чи поєднання цих прийомів. Під час скорочення повинно залишатися не менше ніж дві літери, незалежно від прийому, який використовується. **Під час стягування крапка не ставиться**, під час відсікання крапка ставиться.
>
> > Адміністрація — адмін.
> >     **гривня — грн**
> >     магнітна фонограма на касеті — мф/кас.
>
> Скорочення слова до однієї початкової літери допускається тільки для загальноприйнятих скорочень та окремих слів, приведених у додатку А.
>
> > Рік (роки) — р. (рр).
> >     карта — к.
> >     сторінка — с.

---

Я також нагадаю, що для гривні існує знак [₴](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB_%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%96).